# Error while Importing v7 appcombat for Action bar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, sdk

while importing v7 appcombat file for Action bar, it is not importing the project even after clicking the finish button many times.Also it is not showing any error. The screen remains unresponsive even after clicking the finish button.

Comment: How are you trying to import your v7 appcompat project?